# Como fazer duas querys em um JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Estou montando um mapa usando a API mapbox, criando alguns pontos dinamicamente no mapa.
Tenho um JSON que me passa algumas informações (getDados.php), porém eu queria realizar mais uma query dentro desse arquivo e pegar mais alguns dados de outras tabelas.

```
   //getDados.php
  //Conectando ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "nota");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

//Consultando banco de dados
$qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT p.*, c.`cliente` AS nome,c.`latitude` as latitude,c.`longitude` as longitude, p.`data_inicio` as data_inicio,p.`data_termino` as data_termino FROM `triagem` AS p INNER JOIN `clientes` AS c ON p.`fk_cliente` = c.`id` ORDER BY p.`cliente` ASC");
while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
    $fk_triagem = $resultado["id"];
    $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado);
  }

//Passando vetor em forma de json
echo json_encode($vetor2);
die();
```

Depois disso eu pego esses dados e trabalho com eles em um arquivo JS

```
//index.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
        dataType: 'json',   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
        url: '../mapa/getDados.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    })
    .done(function(response) {

        for(var i=0;response.length>i;i++) {
            var triagem = [response[i].longitude,response[i].latitude];
            var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
              .setText('Construction on the Washington Monument began in 1848.')
              .setHTML('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><p class="lead">Triagem</p><p><strong>Cliente: </strong>'+ response[i].nome +' <\/p><strong>Data de ínicio: </strong>' + response[i].data_inicio + '<\/p><strong>Data de término:</strong> ' + response[i].data_termino + '<p><strong>Técnicos:</strong> xxxx<p><strong>Quantidade de peças previstas:</strong> ' + response[i].total + '<\/p><strong>Quantidade de peças triadas:</strong> xxx</div></div>')
              .addTo(map);
              // create DOM element for the marker
              var el = document.createElement('div');
              el.id = 'marker';
              new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
              .setLngLat(triagem)
              .setPopup(popup) // sets a popup on this marker
              .addTo(map);
        }
    })
});
```

Tem como nesse mesmo arquivo getDados.php, retornar mais algumas informações ? Talvez criar um $vetor2 ou algo assim?

Comment: Você pode retornar um vetor de vetores, assim o vetor pode conter o retorno de duas tabelas, outra coisa que no seu código você está retornando `$vetor2` poderia mostrar-nos onde ele é definido?

Comment: Não é só enviar uma nova solicitação via Ajax? No Ajax vc envia variáveis para o arquivo `getDados.php` e nesse arquivo vc monta a query que quiser de acordo com as variáveis enviadas.

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc só quer executar mais de uma query, pode fazer como vc mesmo disse em um vetor  mas dai vc vai ter q alterar a forma como vc trata no JS, no caso vc pode dar um `array_push($result, $query1)` e `array_push($result, $query2)` e dar  `echo json_encode($result)`